# Validar rango de fechas con data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario el cual tiene dos campos de tipo fecha (fecha inicio, fecha fin respectivamente) al ingresar en el campo fecha inicio por ejemplo 26-06-2019 no debería poder ingresar en fecha fin una fecha inferior a eso, solo una superior. Toda esta validación en forma dinámica obteniendo la fecha que selecciono en el input el usuario.

Estuve probando con el data annotation `[Range]` pero no me deja colocar una fecha dinámica o mas bien no se como hacerlo.

Mi codigo

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2016", Convert.ToString(DateTime.MaxValue))]
```

Esta validación la tengo en mi input fecha fin.

Cabe señalar que el código que coloque no me funciona por que me da un error al querer asignar en el segundo parámetro esto `Convert.ToString(DateTime.MaxValue)`

Answer (score 1):

No se puede validar de forma dinamica usando el `Range` para esto deberas crear un `custom Validation`

Para hacerlo simple existen extensiones

[MVC Validation Extensions](https://brosteins.com/mvc-validation-extensions/)

que agregas usando nuget

[MvcValidationExtensions nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcValidationExtensions)

entonces podras definir

```
[GreaterThanEqualTo("FechaInicio")]
public DateTime? FechaFin { get; set; }
```

---

Aunque yo recomendaria analices usar `Fluent Validation` es mucho mejor a usar atributos ya que puede definir reglas

[Validating Start/End Dates with Fluent Validation for MVC 4](https://www.onthefencedevelopment.com/validating-startend-dates-fluent-validation-mvc-4/)

[fluentvalidation ASP.NET MVC 5 Integration](https://fluentvalidation.net/mvc5)

entnces defines la rule

```
 RuleFor(m => m.EndDate)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End date is required")
        .GreaterThan(m => m.StartDate.Value)
                        .WithMessage("End date must after Start date")
        .When(m => m.StartDate.HasValue);
```